# How to make active tab background as a parent background-image

Tags: html, css

I have a codepen
[link](https://codepen.io/aidosmen/pen/WNLOMYO)
the issue is I want to make active tab background like a continue of the parent background image. Also as you see the tabs shows the paret of images between gap and near border-radius which is not acceptable as well.

```
<div class="container">...
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-width: 540px;
  background-image:  url("https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/5ZjPpfAhn1rZWeopnHiXb/3e1b9a709297905672a0d24eac94a873/thumb_nov22_03.jpg");
}
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
/*  куски image чтобы не было видно между табами  */
}

.tab-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.tab-item .active {
/* быть такого же цвета как и image   */
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-item active">one</div>
    <div class="tab-item">two</div>
    <div class="tab-item">three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo cumque veniam magni earum aliquam suscipit minus natus neque ut, velit alias odio porro numquam accusantium! Assumenda autem aliquid corporis. Cupiditate.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check these out [background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is slightly unclear but it seems like you were wanting this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-width: 540px;
}
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
/*  куски image чтобы не было видно между табами  */
}

.tab-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tab-item.active {
  background-image:  url("https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/5ZjPpfAhn1rZWeopnHiXb/3e1b9a709297905672a0d24eac94a873/thumb_nov22_03.jpg");
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
    background-image:  url("https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/5ZjPpfAhn1rZWeopnHiXb/3e1b9a709297905672a0d24eac94a873/thumb_nov22_03.jpg");
  background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-item active">one</div>
    <div class="tab-item">two</div>
    <div class="tab-item">three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo cumque veniam magni earum aliquam suscipit minus natus neque ut, velit alias odio porro numquam accusantium! Assumenda autem aliquid corporis. Cupiditate.</div>
</div>
```

Essentially what I did is I just put the background image on the active tab and the content and then offset the content by the height of the tab. I gave the tab an explicit height to make sure it was pixel perfect as well.

Comment: partial working as when I make active on 2nd tab picture the transition between tab and content is not smooth but I wil put it is as a solution